# Gif BLOB loaded from database doesn't work

Tags: php, image, header, blob, gif

I have a gif saved as a BLOB in the database, loaded manually in phpMyAdmin.

I want to show it with a little external script where i got the code. The code is:

```
require("_principal.php");

$parrafo = getParrafo($_GET['id_parrafo']);
header("Content-type: image/gif");  
echo $parrafo["archivo_imagen_parrafo"];
```

"_principal.php" is where i made the query to the database. Nothing new.

"$parrafo" contains the data retrieved from the database. Among them, the BLOB data. This works fine so far.

I send the header and echo the BLOB data, which is contained in the field "$parrafo["archivo_imagen_parrafo"]", but nothing happens.

What im doing wrong? Maybe is something with the server? Im using WAMP, PHP 5.4.3 and Apache 2.2.22.

I made the exact same thing with a mp3 file, and worked perfectly.

If you can help me, it will very appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Matías.

Comment: "nothing happens" is a bit vague. Does the browser get a 200 response from the server? What is the content length received by the browser? If the content length is > 0 what does it contain? Have you tried making sure to just output the data to HTML (without the header info) to make sure your query is executing properly?

Comment: What is in the `view source` of the page?

Comment: @BA_Webimax I look at the console when i execute the script and all seems normal, if that is what you mean. Where i can look the 200 response? In Firebug?
I also print_r the $parrafo and that show me all the gibberish saved in the BLOB fields. 

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The code where i call the script is: 

<img src="functions/_imagen_parrafo.php?id_parrafo=2">

"_imagen_parrafo.php" is the script where i made the query, header, echo and so.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @owndod Yes Firebug or the Firefox console. There should be details like content length, etc. in there.

Comment: @BA_Webimax Yes, i get a 200 OK response and the size is > 0. But in the "response tab" shows me an image corrupted, like when you put a wrong url. Thanks.

Comment: @owndod That sounds like an extra character got into the insert or something may have been "translated" by going through PHPMyAdmin. Can you verify the data in the BLOB or can you try reinserting via a PHP function or from the MySQL console?

Comment: @BA_Webimax I tried the same thing with a png, but nothing happened. I will try uploading by php. Maybe is something with base64_decode or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: @BA_Webimax Also, i didnt tell you this, but i added a file_put_contents() and worked perfectly saving the file in the disk, so i assume that the blob is saved correctly in the database.